# Call to script on a server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the process of learning how to make a chrome extension. I decided to look over code from other extensions. One of them has a content script foo.js, after it loads, then fooscript.js loads. There is no call to fooscript.js anywhere in any of the files, neither is it part of the package. It's on a server somewhere. How do you do this?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How does `footscript.js` load? Usually once it's loaded in the page, it will be executed.

Comment: extensions can do cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest and retrive data from external resources.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's loaded. It just starts running after foo.js completes execution. It's not part of the html and it's not a local file. I've tried searching for "fooscript" in all the files and it's not in any of them. I came across this while stepping through the code in the chrome debugger.